# Stepping over from Concurrency to Parallel processing

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a quad core cpu, and I've been trying to experiment with multithreading for performance reasons. I've written this code below just to see how fast it would go, and I noticed that it's actually slower than the 2nd code block that only uses the main thread

```
int numCrunchers = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
public void crunch() {
    int numPairs = 1000;

    for(int i=0; i < numPairs; i++)
        pairs.add(...);

    int share = pairs.size()/numCrunchers;

    for(int i=0; i < numCrunchers; i++) {
        Cruncher cruncher = crunchers.get(i);

        for(int j=0; j < share; j++)
            cruncher.nodes.add(pairs.poll());
    }

    for(Cruncher cruncher : crunchers)
        threadpool.execute(cruncher);

    threadpool.shutdown();

    try {
        threadpool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private class Cruncher implements Runnable {
    public BlockingQueue<Pair<PathNode>> nodes = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Pair<PathNode>>();
    private AStarPathfinder pathfinder;
    private LinkedList<PathNode> path = new LinkedList<PathNode>();

    public Cruncher(GridGraph graph) {
        pathfinder = new AStarPathfinder(graph);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            path.clear();
            Pair<PathNode> pair = nodes.poll();
            if(pair != null) {
                pathfinder.search(path, pair.first(), pair.second());
                paths.add(new LinkedList<PathNode>(path));
            } else {
                System.out.println("This cruncher is done");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Each thread took around 34,000,000,000 nanoseconds on my pc, but when I decided to use no threads except for the main thread, it only took 1,090,195,046 nanoseconds, 34x time difference.

```
    LinkedList<Pair<PathNode>> pairs = new LinkedList<Pair<PathNode>>();
    int numPairs = 1000;
    AStarPathfinder pathfinder = new AStarPathfinder(graph);

    for(int i=0; i < numPairs; i++)
        pairs.add(...);

    long current = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0; i < numPairs; i++) {
        Pair<PathNode> pair = pairs.poll();
        path.clear();
        pathfinder.search(path, pair.first(), pair.second());
    }
    System.out.printf("Operation took %d nanoseconds", System.nanoTime() - current);
```

My question is why using multiple threads causes my program to run slow? Is the code not properly taking advantage of all the cores on my cpu? I ran this several times, and the results were similar, (30+)x time difference between multithreading and single-threading

**Edit**: 
Decided to measure the time of each individual operation on the multithreaded

```
    while(true) {
        path.clear();
        Pair<PathNode> pair = nodes.poll();
        if(pair != null) {
            long current = System.nanoTime();
            pathfinder.search(path, pair.first(), pair.second());
            paths.add(new LinkedList<PathNode>(path));
            System.out.printf("Took %d nanoseconds\n", System.nanoTime() - current);
        } else {
            System.out.println("This cruncher is done");
            break;
        }
    }
```

and single threaded...

```
    LinkedList<Pair<PathNode>> pairs = new LinkedList<Pair<PathNode>>();
    int numPairs = 1000;
    AStarPathfinder pathfinder = new AStarPathfinder(graph);

    for(int i=0; i < numPairs; i++)
        pairs.add(...);

    for(int i=0; i < numPairs; i++) {
        long current = System.nanoTime();
        Pair<PathNode> pair = pairs.poll();
        path.clear();
        pathfinder.search(path, pair.first(), pair.second());
        System.out.printf("Operation took %d nanoseconds", System.nanoTime() - current);
    }
```

Each Cruncher has its own AStarPathfinder instance, so the pathfinder.search() couldn't be causing blocking between each of the threads. The multithreaded application was still much slower.

Comment: This could be due to multiple reasons. Creating and starting  threads is expensive. Context switching between threads adds to this as well. Try doing something which takes  some *milliseconds*. You will perhaps see some difference. Try doing an operation which will take a couple of seconds (on main thread), you will (most probably) see a drastic change in the performance for the 2 code blocks

Comment: I changed the numPairs value to 5000, and measured the time it took for each search inside of each cruncher. This is what I found. Each search on the multithreading application took around 123,235,110 to 153,037,850 nanoseconds while on the singlethreaded, the longest operation was 2,564,662 nanoseconds. Adding more work to the threads didn’t seem to do much and It appears that each of the threads are sharing one core.

Comment: I guess that just creating the threads (expensive, as mentioned) and copying the data to them (which you do serially when creating the threads) taks a lot of time. Since the crunching itself does not seem to take much time itself, performing 750 or even 3750 extra crunches is still significantly shorter than all that copying